# How to get the coordinates of pins in Google Map automatically?

Tags: google-maps

If you go to http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/departments/nrd-30/ncsa/STSI/27_MN/2013/Minnesota_Map_1_GIS_DATA_2013.HTM and check one of the check boxes on the top right corner (2011, 2012, 2013), you will get many pins on the map. If I click any of those pins, a popup window will give lat/lon information which is what I want to collect.

Is there a way to do that automatically? I am not sure which tools to use , so any guide is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick, upon inspection of the code. It is clearly commented that the map has been generated using Google Fusion Tables ([here](http://www.smalldatajournalism.com/projects/one-offs/mapping-with-fusion-tables/) is the link about it). [Here](http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/departments/nrd-30/ncsa/STSI/Auxiliary_Files/Fusion_Maps.js) is the fusion table java script file for your link in which you could see the key for the current fusion table. We can use that key(11Oknh0ERme3SJx3NFNJ7oQhYMI8pPHhvxonqapaa) and put it in the google fusion tables url which turns out to be the data available at: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=11Oknh0ERme3SJx3NFNJ7oQhYMI8pPHhvxonqapaa (probably needs you logged in). That is an expanded version of an excel file consisting all the data columns. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!